# How to add data to dynamodb using lambda which i invoke using rule engine

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am new to AWS IOT.
I have created a table in Dynamodb and i have created a Thing in aws iot.
I know we can add data to Dynamodb directly using a Rule,
But instead I want to Invoke a Rule that calls a `lambda` function when data arrives to aws iot and and send that data to same `lambda` function and add the data to Dynamodb using the same `lambda` function.

So how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some templates on AWS Lambda that you can use to save data to DynamoDB.
Your data for AWS Iot will come as the "event" parameter to the lambda_handler function.
Process this data as you want and then use [DynamoDB API - PutItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) to insert data into your table.

Comment: Thank you for the Guidance. Your answer helped me a lot @dvd86